# How to count the number of times number 7 appears in an array

Tags: c, computer-science

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define LEN 5

int main() 
{ 
int i;
int count = 0;
 size_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)*LEN); 

while(1){

 for(i=0;i<LEN;i++){ 
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]); 
 } 


 for(i=0;i < ptr[i]; i++){ 

     if(ptr = NULL || sizeof(ptr) < 0){
    printf("nah");
 } else if(ptr[i] == 7){
            ++count;
        }
  } printf("%d", count);
    break;
  }
 free(ptr); 
 return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to find the number of times that the number 7 appears in malloc.. Counting works well but how should I show that if the malloc`s size is less than zero, or if it`s NULL, it has to return -1?

Also, what does it mean by returning -1? I am very new with C programming...
Any help would be so thankful!

Comment: `ptr = NULL` assigns `NULL` to the pointer, it's not what you intended.

Comment: Please: for your own sake, format your code correctly.

Comment: Hint: `size_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)*LEN);`: it's pointless to allocate memory dynamically for a constant size (`LEN`). You can write `size_t ptr[LEN];` instead and drop `free(ptr);`.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);`  --> `scanf("%zu", &ptr[i]);`,  `i < ptr[i]` --> `i < LEN`

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't provide any direct facilities for letting the program know there was an error in a function, so instead we rely on the return values of functions.

For example, in your case, it only makes sense for there to be a size of 0 or greater.  If an "error" occurs, you can return -1, and anyone waiting for the result of the program will see the result as invalid, and assume there was an error of some sort.

Because this isn't baked into the C language itself, enforcement is purely by convention.  If the person who runs your program doesn't check the value, and uses "-1" like they would use "5", they will run into problems that don't have an obvious cause.

Functions provided by the standard libraries often carry their own conventions for return values and errors. `malloc` is one of these.  Checking the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), the "return value" is NULL on a failure.  For functions that return pointers, returning NULL as a failure is a common convention.

In your code you can add

`size_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)*LEN); 
if (ptr == NULL) {return -1;}`

to properly check the return value.

You want to check for a null value as soon as you can, because using `ptr` when it could be NULL can lead to [segfaults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Another note, your use of `sizeof` is suspect in `sizeof(ptr) < 0`.  Sizeof is either called on types like `int` or `size_t`, or on variables.  In this case, you will get the size of the pointer type, as if you called `sizeof(size_t*)`. Check out [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

One last note, you're making `ptr` of type `size_t*`.  Pointer types are almost like integers, or other number types, so the `sizeof(ptr) < 0` condition will never be false.  It seems like you're new to C, which uses uses pointers and other low-level concepts that you wouldn't have seen in other languages.  Before continuing too much further, I'd recommend solidifying your understanding of memory and pointers in C.  Some resources I use are: [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm), [Class websites](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html), [Nice free guides](http://boredzo.org/pointers/), and [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays)

Good luck!

Comment: Very good answer for a beginner to read and comprehend. However, note that `sizeof` can definitely be used on expressions/variables as well. Check out the same link you've given, point number 2 in that page!  :)

Comment: Thanks for catching that, changing now

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

This is pointless inside the `for` loop, you should do that test right after calling `malloc`:

```
if(ptr = NULL || sizeof(ptr) < 0){
   printf("nah");
```

testing `sizeof(ptr) < 0` is also pointless (but doesn't hurt here), because the type of `sizeof` is unsigned and it won't be negative anyway.

It's `if (ptr == NULL)` instead of `if (ptr = NULL)`.

The `while` loop is pointless, you are breaking out of it unconditionally.

After `printf("nah");` the program should exit and not proceed any further.

And indentation of your program is terrible, it is difficult to read.

This is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define LEN 5

int main()
{
  int i;
  int count = 0;
  size_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(size_t)*LEN);

  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("nah");
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i<LEN; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    if (ptr[i] == 7) {
      ++count;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", count);

  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);` --> `scanf("%zu", &ptr[i]);`